# ¿cuál sería la diferencia entre usar un pool o usar una conexion tradicional a la base de datos?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, base-de-datos, connection, pool

Estoy usando angular con node.js y mySql, usé un pool porque en el tutorial en el que me estaba basando lo usaban, así que simplemente lo usé por eso. Según entiendo un Pool es un grupo de conexiones, se puede establecer un limite entre sus parámetros al momento de crearl.

En wikipedia está esta definición:

> Al mantenerse abierto un grupo de conexiones, éstas son atribuidas a los diferentes hilos de ejecución únicamente el tiempo de una transacción con la base de datos. Al finalizar su utilización, la conexión se pone a disposición de otro hilo de ejecución que necesite de ese recurso, en lugar de cerrarla o de asignarla permanentemente a un único hilo de ejecución.

Eso quiere decir que al hacer una consulta automática el pool se encarga de cerrarla o yo tendría que cerrarla igual que cuándo se trabaja con una conexión tradicional?

en la documentación de MySql NPM veo esto:

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});
 
pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```

simplemente crean el pool y automáticamente pueden hacer una consulta y listo.

Luego muestran este código donde obtienen una conexión, hacen una consulta y luego finalizan esa conexión:

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool(...);
 
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  if (err) throw err; // not connected!
 
  // Use the connection
  connection.query('SELECT something FROM sometable', function (error, results, fields) {
    // When done with the connection, release it.
    connection.release();
 
    // Handle error after the release.
    if (error) throw error;
 
    // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.
  });
});
```

1) Yo tengo una aplicación donde hasta ahora llevo el registro del usuario, y simplemente creaba el pool, y luego hacía las operaciones para el insert, y nunca obtenía una conexión y mucho menos la finalizaba. Estaría mal hacerlo así? por qué?

2) Que sería lo recomendable, hacerlo de la segunda forma que muestran en la documentación, obtener una conexión, realizar operaciones y cerrarla ?

Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar a aclarar esta duda.

Answer (score 2):

Abrir y cerrar conexiones de base de datos (i.e. conexiones de sockets tcp o similares) toma algún tiempo. Especialmente en aplicaciones Web, en las que no es para nada bueno tener que abrir un nueva conexión para cada acción del usuario, lo que suele hacerse es tener un pequeño `pool` de conexiones que siempre están abiertas y son compartidas entre los usuarios. Un pool de conexiones *mantiene un número de conexiones a la base datos abiertas* y este número puede variar dependiendo de la carga del servicio. De forma en lugar de abrir tu mismo una nueva conexión simplemente solicitas alguna de las disponibles, *mejorando de esta forma el desempeño de tu aplicación*. El no cerrar tus conexiones y abrir nuevas cada que las necesitas es un desperdicio de recursos y conducirá a un mal desempeño de la misma.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool(...);

// En este punto le pides al pool que te pase una de sus conexiones ya abiertas 
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  if (err) throw err; // not connected!

  // Se utiliza la conexión
  connection.query('SELECT something FROM sometable', function (error, results, fields) {
    // La conexión no se cierra, siemplemente se libera para que se pueda usar por otro proceso
    connection.release();

    if (error) throw error;

    // Si hay algún error en este punto el recurso ya se encuentra de nuevo disponible en el pool.
  });
});
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad

**EDIT** No hay un peor o mejor método, ambos son validos, pero dependerá de las circunstancias, el pirmer caso con `pool.query()` es muy útil cuando se realiza una sola consulta a la base de datos, ya que libera la conexión de forma automática, sin embargo, en casos donde se requiera ejecutar una sucesión de consultas en una misma transacción lo mejor será utilizar `pool.getConnection()` pero en esos casos será **necesario** liberar la conexión explícitamente con `connection.release()`

Algo que puede ayudarte facilitar la creación de conexiones de tu app es definir la la función para obtener la conexión en un modulo separado de tu app:

```
var getConnection = function(callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        callback(err, connection);
    });
};

module.exports = getConnection;
```

Y simplemente importarla donde desees utilizar la conexión, aunque, de esta forma tendrás que librar la conexión siempre que la ocupes.

Comment: Estaría mal si se hace de la primera forma que comento en mi pregunta ? Así aparece en la documentación también.

Comment: Entiendo que si no lo hago con el getConnection por ejemplo, si tengo un método donde simplemente hago pool.query (sin haber hecho. GetConnection, al finalizar ese metodo, la conexión se libera ? Disculpa, es que sigo sin entender la diferencia si la libero yo o dejo que la libere la librería automáticamente o es que no entiendo bien aún como funciona.

Comment: @JulianProg  Efectivamente, si haces `pool.query` la conexión se liberará de forma automática, y en el segundo caso `getConnection` debes forzosamente liberarla de forma explicita o tu aplicación se quedará esperando hasta que lo hagas una vez que alcances el limite de conexiones definidas en el pool. Te sugiero que leas la info en el siguiente enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54224377/12335544

Answer (score 0):

Un pool de conexiones es una abstracción. Ofrece a tu aplicación un conjunto (un pool) de conexiones a la base de datos, pero realmente son equivalentes a sesiones. La conexión, el socket que se abre al puerto en el servidor de la BD, es uno solo y eso hace que sea más eficiente.

Cuando tu aplicación pide una conexión al pool, realmente lo que hace es solicitar que le asigne una de las sesiones abiertas en la BD que el pool se encarga de mantener vivas de acuerdo a como lo configures (el pool le dice a los demás si hay sesiones disponibles o todas están prestadas)... cuando terminas de usarla, se la devuelves al pool y este la identifica como disponible nuevamente. El pool (para JDBC 4 al menos) puede validar que el socket esté abierto y la comunicación esté viva. En general, se encarga de hacer muchas cosas que tendrías que hacer manualmente y que importan cuando te ocupas de conceptos como concurrencia, latencia y disponibilidad.

Si lo haces como en la primera aproximación, debes encargarte de crear la conexión a nivel de aplicación (la conexión a BD), iniciar la sesión autenticándote en la BD cada vez, ejecutar la consulta y liberar luego los recursos adecuadamente (los statements, connections y resultsets son unos de los principales culpables de memory leaks cuando alguien maneja conexiones JDBC a mano). Si no finalizas el uso de estos recursos (que es una de tus preguntas) vas a tener problemas si tu aplicación corre por un tiempo prolongado, pues se va a quedar sin memoria. Lo otro: uno no necesita finalizar el pool; antaño este era un singleton que se instanciaba una única vez para toooda la aplicación (no se necesita más de una instancia sirviendo todas las peticiones).

¿Cuál es mejor? Pues eso va en opiniones y necesidades. En una aplicación de uso productivo, uno siempre va a preferir no reinventar la rueda y usará un pool que optimice el uso de recursos y garantice tiempos de respuesta buenos. Para un ejercicio en clase posiblemente no sea necesario.

Comment: Tuve esa duda porque en la documentación muestran la primera forma tal cual, es decir, no veo que finalicen la conexión allí, y así lo dejé, pero dices que se debería cerrar igual que se hace en la segunda forma? Aunque entiendo que las conexiones no se cierran, solo se finalizan, porque siguen estando activas.